# Unexpected lemmatize result from gensim

Tags: nlp, nltk, gensim, lemmatization

I used following code lemmatize texts that were already excluding stop words and kept words longer than 3. However, after using following code, it split existing words such as 'wheres' to ['where', 's']; 'youre' to ['-PRON-','be']. I didn't expect 's', '-PRON-', 'be' these results in my text, what caused this behaviour and what I can do?

```
def lemmatization(texts, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV']):
"""https://spacy.io/api/annotation"""

texts_out = []
for sent in texts:
    doc = nlp(" ".join(sent)) 
    texts_out.append([token.lemma_ for token in doc]) # though rare, if only keep the tokens with given posttags, add 'if token.pos_ in allowed_postags'
return texts_out

# Initialize spacy 'en' model, keeping only tagger component (for efficiency)
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])

data_lemmatized = lemmatization(data_words_trigrams, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV'])
```

Comment: This is how SpaCy works.  It tokenizes the words (including splitting out contractions) and returns the lemma of a pronoun as -PRON- (since there really isn't a lemma for pronouns).  Most NLP systems work similarly.  If you want different behavior you'll have to specify how you want things to work since this is the expected.

Comment: Thank you Bivouac0, so you suggest doing another round stop-word cleaning after lemmatization? Any other suggestion for the cleaning? Thank you.